# How to run waitress for a socket.io server without flask in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, socket.io, waitress

Am using Windows 11 and I wish to run a python socket.io server. **gunicorn** being incompatible with Windows, I tried using **waitress** to run my server using the following command `waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 app:pysock` and it throwed me the following exception.

> There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module.
>
> It had these arguments:
>
> 1. No module named 'app'

Here is my python code :

```py
# filename is pysock.py
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
static_files={
    "/":"./public/"
}
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio,static_files=static_files)

@sio.event
def connect(sid,environ):
    print(sid,"connected")

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print(sid,"disconnected")
```

All solutions on stack overflow were based on Flask app and am **not using Flask**. Is there any way to solve this exception ?

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be filename : WSGI parameter name:

```
waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 pysock:app
```

This worked for me on Windows 10.